# How to make tf.nn.conv2d produce stable result?

Tags: tensorflow

When I use tf.nn.conv2d with the stride larger than the filter size, the outputs of conv2d are different across difference Session.run().
Can I make tf.nn.conv2d produce deterministic output?

I test the following code with tensorflow on the master branch, cuda 7.5 and cudnn v5.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

input_batch_size = 1
input_height = 80
input_width = 80
input_num_channels = 100

filter_height = 1
filter_width = 1
output_num_channels= 30
stride = 2

nn_input = tf.placeholder(shape=[input_batch_size, input_height, input_width,
                                                     input_num_channels],
                                        dtype=tf.float32)
f = tf.get_variable('f', shape=[filter_height, filter_width, input_num_channels, 
                                              output_num_channels],
                             initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())

conv = tf.nn.conv2d(nn_input, f, strides=[1, stride, stride, 1], 
                    padding='SAME', use_cudnn_on_gpu=True)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

i = np.random.random([input_batch_size, input_height,
                      input_width, input_num_channels])

for _ in range(10000):
    diff = np.abs(sess.run(conv, feed_dict={nn_input: i}) - 
                  sess.run(conv, feed_dict={nn_input: i})).max()
    if diff:
        print(diff) # print 30.9991
        break
```

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but just in case you want this for the resolution-changing modules in ResNet, I ran into similar issues and had good results adding an avg-pooling layer with a size/stride of 2 and a 1x1 conv with stride 1 instead of the 1x1 conv with stride 2 - it is not the same as in the paper but it seems to work as well

Comment: Thank you @etarion! I will try your suggestions to downsample feature maps. I found if I set `use_cudnn_on_gpu` for tf.nn.conv2d to False, conv2d will produce deterministic output. I am curious if there is a better way to do this with cudnn.